# Unusual use of the word "equipped" - correct or incorrect?

Tags: word-usage

A car-enthusiast website I frequent often, Bringatrailer.com, uses the word "equipped" in what seems to me like an unnatural and incorrect way.

I'd like to know if their usage is correct or not.

Their site lists attributes of cars that are for sale. Here are a few examples of how they use the word "equipped":

*Aluminum bumpers are equipped. 
A factory Tire Inflation System is equipped.
An aftermarket turn signal kit is equipped.
A Schroeder steering box is equipped.
Independent suspension is equipped front and rear.
A removable roof panel is equipped.
A red emblem is equipped on the front grille.*

These all sound wrong to me. One easy fix that sounds correct to me would be to substitute either "fitted" or "installed."

*Aluminum bumpers are fitted. 
A factory Tire Inflation System is installed.
An aftermarket turn signal kit is fitted.
A Schroeder steering box is installed.
Independent suspension is fitted front and rear.
A removable roof panel is installed.
A red emblem is fitted on the front grille.*

If the word "equipped" was preferred, it seems to me that the phrases need to be restructured, like this:

*The car is equipped with Aluminum bumpers. 
The car is equipped with a factory Tire Inflation System.
The car is equipped with an aftermarket turn signal kit.
The car is equipped with a Schroeder steering box.
The car is equipped with Independent suspension front and rear.
The car is equipped with a removable roof panel.
The front grille is equipped with a red emblem.*

I'd appreciate expert opinions about this, thanks!

Comment: In a question like this, please report what you found in a dictionary.  If none of the definitions in your dictionary fit this usage, tell us that.

Comment: I'm new at this. I'm not asking about the definition, I'm asking if the the sentence structure is correct for using that word. Maybe this should be tagged differently.